# How to setup local website with a certain domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

In a old PC, I installed `Ubuntu server 14.04` and I want to use this server to host some websites and web applications that will be available in my network. I installed `Apache` and when I click in the browser the IP of my server I successfully see the Apache's webpage.

Lets say, I have a static website which is accessible from `192.168.0.10/mysite.html`. Is it possible to access this site from a certain domain (e.g. mydomain.mycompany.gr) which will work only under my network?

I tried and I create a virtual host, using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) but it didn't worked..

Comment: @AnthonyFornito due to `off-topic` question

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AnthonyFornito I'm not mod. I suggest unix stack as it covers unix & linux related questions (learning), serverfault is for business environment.

Comment: @AnthonyFornito Why don't you move your ranting complaints to meta.serverfault.com where it belongs?

Comment: Thx @AnthonyFornito for the support. The truth is that I am total newbie to all this. That's why I setup the server in order to test it and learn things.. and also I don't understand why is off topic from serverfault site. The question is about how to configure the server. And yes, the server is under a business network...

Comment: @yaylitzis take a look at this http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you setup everything on the server correctly:

In the walk through TL;DR is didn't see updating your apache.conf you have NameVirtualHost *:80 in there to server up domain names.

Secondly if this is just for your network and for testing, i am also assuming you do not have a DNS server anywhere, use the local hosts file on your local pc to map the domainname to your IP address name.

Follow this if you have any questions about how to do that:

https://support.aiso.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/240/2/how-do-i-add-my-domain-name-to-my-computers-host-file